# Кеширование комментариев с переключателем страниц

Tags: php, mysql, кэширование

Как это правильно сделать? Есть новость, которая берется из кеша news123.html и на странице к список комментариев с переключателем страниц, к примеру 100 комментариев, и 10 страниц, т.е . 1 страница = 10 комментариев

Как это правильно закешировать в файл? Допустим я удалил часть комментариев, и что? Нужно список страниц перестроить, в mysql я использовал SELECT с LIMIT 0 10 а в файле кеша как?

Answer (score 0):

А вы кешируйте не всю страницу, у вас же наверняка страница состоит из частей шаблона, закешируйте отдельно хедер, футер ... и отдельно часть шаблона с самим контентом, а операция сборки частей шаблона во едино дешевая по ресурсам. Коментарии и вовсе не кешируйте, или кешируйте как-то по частям, например первых 10 комментариев закешируйте и обновляйте кеш при добавлении/удалении коментов, а если человек хочет увидеть остальные коменты, то догенерируйте и покажите.

А классный вариант это когда вы комментарии будете подтягивать используя ajax. Тогда можете кешировать что угодно)